# How to find the mean of each quarter?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this code where i need to find the mean of the approval for each quarter.

```
approval <- read_csv('covid_approval_polls.csv')
quarters2 <- approval %>% 
             select(start_date, end_date, approve) %>% 
             filter(approval$party == 'all') %>% 
             mutate(Quarter = as.yearqtr(approval$start_date)) %>% 
             group_by(Quarter) %>%  
             summarise(AVERAGE = ceiling(mean(approval$approve, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

I am trying to use dplyr which I think is correct but my code gives me the mean of all the data.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your code looks reasonable, apart from the references to `approval` within the pipe.  Remove them: they are not necessary.  Without seeing (some of) your input data, it will be difficult to help you more.

Comment: As Limey mentioned you are passing the full data with `approval$approve`.  It should be `approval` alone

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out and you are totally right. Thanks